# How to load dataset with pandas dataframes into Spacy?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, text, nlp

I currently have text data with pandas dataframe. I would like to do *part of speech* tags with Spacy library. But I don't know how to import load data from pandas into Spacy.

Does anybody know how to load data from pandas dataframe into Spacy? Thank you!

Here is my dataset:

```
df = pd.concat([jsons_data,label],axis=1)

text    title   authors label
0   On Saturday, September 17 at 8:30 pm EST, an e...   Another Terrorist Attack in NYC…Why Are we STI...   [View All Posts, Leonora Cravotta]  Real
1   Story highlights "This, though, is certain: to...   Hillary Clinton on police shootings: 'too many...   [Mj Lee, Cnn National Politics Reporter]    Real
2   Critical Counties is a CNN series exploring 11...   Critical counties: Wake County, NC, could put ...   [Joyce Tseng, Eli Watkins]  Real
3   McCain Criticized Trump for Arpaio’s Pardon… S...   NFL Superstar Unleashes 4 Word Bombshell on Re...   []  Real
4   Story highlights Obams reaffirms US commitment...   Obama in NYC: 'We all have a role to play' in ...   [Kevin Liptak, Cnn White House Producer]    Real
5   Obama weighs in on the debate\n\nPresident Bar...   Obama weighs in on the debate   [Brianna Ehley, Jack Shafer]
```

This is my code to load data into Spacy:

```
import spacy
from dframcy import DframCy
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
dframcy = DframCy(nlp)
doc = dframcy.nlp(df)
annotation_dataframe = dframcy.to_dataframe(doc)

TypeError: Argument 'string' has incorrect type (expected str, got DataFrame)
```

Comment: this is an assumption : you are interested in the text column. spacy only works on strings and has no concept of a dataframe. create a string that combines all of the text column : s = '.'.join(df['text'].tolist()). I use dot as a separator to mimic sentences in the string. then u can pass s into doc and proceed : doc = dframcy.nlp(s).

Comment: ah okay i will try thank you! @sammywemmy

Comment: @sammywemmy It works! Thank you so much for your help!